# Laravel Cartalyst Sentinel can't rollback migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, migration, cartalyst-sentinel

I can't rollback all migrations.
When I'm running `php artisan migrate:reset` all my migrations rolling back except Sentinel. And I getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MigrationCartalystSentinel' not found in /home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php on line 301
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/artisan:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/artisan:59
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:124
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:193
PHP   5. Illuminate\Console\Command->run() /home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:889
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:100
PHP   7. Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() /home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:253
PHP   8. Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\ResetCommand->fire() /home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:112
PHP   9. Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->rollback() /home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/ResetCommand.php:61
PHP  10. Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->runDown() /home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:172
PHP  11. Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->resolve() /home/vagrant/Projects/MuzzaLife/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:192
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'MigrationCartalystSentinel' not found","file":"\/home\/vagrant\/Projects\/MuzzaLife\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Migrations\/Migrator.php","line":301}}vagrant@homestead:~/Projects/MuzzaLife$
```

How correct to reset all migration include Cartalyst Sentinel?

Comment: It can't find that class, so have you deleted it or changed the class name?

Comment: Did you publish your migrations? `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\SentinelServiceProvider"`

Comment: @craig_h, this class located in /vendor/cartalyst/sentinel/src/migrations/2014_07_02_230147_migration_cartalyst_sentinel.php

Comment: @Gravy, I'm using Sentinel 1.0 and Laravel 4.2, fnd this command not working for me. I'm getting the following error: "[InvalidArgumentException]                                
  There are no commands defined in the "vendor" namespace."

Comment: @Gravy, I got it. You talking about config. I published config file, but there are no setups for migration.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem yet? I encountered a similar issue on L5.

Comment: @Fester So, is there any solution to it?

Answer (score 2):

The following command should solve the problem:

`composer dump-autoload`